# BizTalk based webservice incoming location is slow

Tags: biztalk

I noticed that sometimes incoming location build on BizTalk WCF-BasicHttp is exactly 15 seconds slower than processing time of this message inside orchestration.

Also I've found that in **Rate based Throttling** for BizTalkServerIsolatedHost **Sampling window duration** is 15 seconds .

Is that possible that for some reason BizTalk start throttling incoming messages this is why webservice start responding 15 seconds longer .

However there are no messages into even log that BizTalk is throttling.

How  can I found what happening with BizTalk ?

Answer (score 1):

To see if BizTalk is throttling you have to monitor the Host Throttling counters using Perfmon.

From [Host Throttling Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx)

> **To access performance counters**
>
> Use the following steps to access the performance counters.
>
> If you are using Windows 2008
>
> 1. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Performance Monitor.
> 2. In the Performance Monitor dialog box, expand Monitoring Tools, select Performance Monitor, and then click Add.
> 3. In the Add Counters dialog box, from the Available Counters list, expand the BizTalk:Message Agent performance counter object and select the counters to be monitored.
> 4. In the Instances of Selected object list, select the specific instances to be monitored for the selected counters and then click Add. To select all available counter instances, select .
> 5. After adding the counters, click OK.
>
> The selected performance counters appear on the Performance Monitor screen.

However I don't think that is your issue, it sounds like you want Low Latency.  For this you need to do [Low-Latency Scenario Optimizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722842(BTS.10).aspx)

Note that the total processing time also includes the time that IIS takes to spin up the web service and publish the message into the message box.  So you might need to also make changes in the Application Pool of the Web Service to stop it tearing down.  Look at the setting Idle Time-out, this is set to 20 minutes by default.  If the web service is hit less often than this time and you want a faster response, set this to a higher value.  Some people also schedule a task to wake the webservice on a regular basis.  This is that even if the appPool is recycled or restarted it is spun up again quickly.

Comment: I've got question about low-latency: if I understood correctly by default it is 500 milliseconds, so this is longest delay  I can get. But it shouldn't be 15 seconds , right ? Thank you answer , I will setup counters to see if it's throttling.